# AttributeError: 'ir.http' object has no attribute 'get_frontend_session_info'

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I am getting this error when accessing my local instance of Odoo

> Error while render the template
> AttributeError: 'ir.http' object has no attribute 'get_frontend_session_info'
> Template: web.frontend_layout".
> Path: /t/html/head/script[2]/t
> Node: <t t-out="json.dumps(request.env['ir.http'].get_frontend_session_info())

Here is my configuration file:

```ini
db_host = localhost 
db_port = 5432 
db_user = odoo17 
db_password = remote 
addons_path = D:\odoo\odoo\addons 
http_port = 8069 
logfile = D:\odoo\logs\odoo.log 
session_dir = D:\\odoo\\sessions 
admin_passwd = admin123
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please, show some code to work with. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is a copy of the exact error from the logs:       AttributeError: 'ir.http' object has no attribute 'get_frontend_session_info'
Template: web.frontend_layout
Path: /t/html/head/script[2]/t
Node: <t t-out="json.dumps(request.env[\'ir.http\'].get_frontend_session_info())

Comment: this is my code : db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo17
db_password = remote
addons_path = D:\odoo\odoo\addons
http_port = 8069
logfile = D:\odoo\logs\odoo.log
session_dir = D:\\odoo\\sessions
admin_passwd = admin123

Comment: @Abdullah comments are not meant to provide code or to further develop your question. When asked further information, rather provide them in an [edit] of your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the `addons_path` you specified in your configuration.
The function `get_frontend_session_info` is provided by the modules in *odoo\addons*.

You should change your `addons_path` to:

```ini
addons_path = D:\odoo\odoo\addons,D:\odoo\addons
```